# D'Alembert criterion

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

can someone explain to me the middle steps between (1), (2), (3)?
This exercise is used as an example of the convergence of series, and I understand the criterion. I don't follow the middle steps.

[image: D'Alembert Criterion Example]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is a typo: the first fraction above (2) should have numerator and denominator exchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fraction above (1) can be rewritten as
$$
\left|\frac{(n+1)^3+\sqrt{n+1}}{(2+4i)^{n+1}}\frac{(2+4i)^n}{n^3+\sqrt{n}}\right|=
\frac{(n+1)^3+\sqrt{n+1}}{n^3+\sqrt{n}}\frac{1}{|2+4i|}
$$
In your image the numerator and denominator are wrongly swapped. The absolute value around the first fraction in the right-hand side is redundant.

It's easy to prove that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^3+\sqrt{n+1}}{n^3+\sqrt{n}}=1
$$
so we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}=\frac{1}{|2+4i|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{20}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{\left|{(n+1)^3+\sqrt{n+1}\over (2+4i)^{n+1}}\right|\over \left|{n^3+\sqrt{n}\over (2+4i)^{n}}\right|}{=\lim_{n\to \infty}{\left|{(n+1)^3+\sqrt{n+1}}\right|\over \left|{n^3+\sqrt{n}}\right|}\cdot \left|{{1\over  (2+4i)^{n+1}}\over {1\over  (2+4i)^{n}}}\right|\\=\lim_{n\to \infty}{\left|{(n+1)^3+\sqrt{n+1}}\right|\over \left|{n^3+\sqrt{n}}\right|}\cdot \left|{{(2+4i)^{n}\over  (2+4i)^{n+1}}}\right|\\=\lim_{n\to \infty}{\left|{(n+1)^3+\sqrt{n+1}}\right|\over \left|{n^3+\sqrt{n}}\right|}\cdot {1\over |2+4i|}\\=1\cdot {1\over \sqrt{20}}\\={1\over \sqrt{20}}}$$